# Texture2D as function parameter

Tags: directx, hlsl

This is in a compute shader, but I think it's a general hlsl thing. Here's a snippet:

```
Texture2D<float> Ground : register(t1);
Texture2D<float> Water : register(t2);

SamplerState LinearSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

float4 Get(Texture2D source, float x, float y)
{
    return source.SampleLevel(LinearSampler, float2(x * dimension.z, y * dimension.w), 0);
}

[numthreads(32, 32, 1)]
void main(uint3 threadID : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint3 groupThreadID : SV_GroupThreadID, uint3 blockID : SV_GroupID)
{
    float4 g = GetGround(Ground, 0, 0);

    Output[threadID.xy] = g.z;
}
```

Any calls to the Get method give me:

error X3017: 'Get': cannot implicitly convert from 'const Texture2D' to 'Texture2D'

Comment: Just a quick guess have you tried `float4 Get(const Texture2D source, float x, float y)` ?

Comment: How do you call `Get()`? With which parameters types?

Comment: Where did you call this function? without the calling code, it's difficult to identify the root cause.

Comment: @Gnietschow I have tried that yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your lack of code tags are causing the angle brackets to be omitted.  The error should be `error X3017: 'Get': cannot implicitly convert from 'const Texture2D<float>' to 'Texture2D<float4>'` right?  This makes sense since `Texture2D` is implicitly `Texture2D<float4>` (4-channel), and your global textures are `Texture2D<float>` (single-channel).  The compiler doesn't expand types implicitly (though it will truncate with a warning).  This is regardless of whether it's a Texture2D or a plain old float4.  To fix your code, you should make sure your source textures are really single-channel, and then make the function argument match (i.e. `Texture2D<float> source`).